# Bookmarklet for selecting code snippets on Code Review

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, stackexchange

The following code will add to each code block a 'Select Code' button that will select the code belonging to that block. Please review for maintainability.

In order to use this, visit http://codereviewcommunity.github.io/CodeReviewBookmarklet/

```
javascript: if ($('button').length === 0) { 
  /* Stack Exchange does not do buttons, this does */
  $(".prettyprint").each( function()
  { 
    /* Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838358/7602 */
    function selectCode(el, win) 
    {
      win = win || window;
      var doc = win.document, sel, range;
      if (win.getSelection && doc.createRange) 
      {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
      } 
      else if (doc.body.createTextRange) 
      {
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
      }
    }

    var buttonText  = 'Select Code',
        length      = buttonText.length,
        codeBlock   = this,
        $link       = $('<button type="button">' + buttonText + '</button><br>').click(function()
        {
          console.log( $(codeBlock).text().substring( length ) );
          selectCode(codeBlock);
        });
    $(codeBlock).prepend( $link );
  });
}
```

I have tested this on FF and Chrome and it works for me.

Comment: Works on Safari 7.

Comment: How do you test this with Chrome?

Comment: Select the test, then mouse-down for half a second, and then drag the code into the bookmark-bar.

Comment: Nice!  You could consider putting the updated code below the original, while clearly marking it as such.

Comment: @Jamal I don't like the button size with `before`, I will have to play with it a bit.

Comment: Okay.  Do you also need to update what I've put on your post, assuming it only works that way with Chrome?

Comment: I am thinking to actually make this a subproject of our github account, with a page where you can indeed drag/drop a link to the bookmark bar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You inject the button using [`jQuery.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), which inserts the button as the first child of the `.prettyprint` code block.  Therefore, when the bookmarklet is invoked, and it selects the contents of the code block, the "Select Code" button is inadvertently included in the selection.  I recommend using [`jQuery.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) instead.

Comment: You are right, will fix. On FF, the text of the button does not actually make it into the clipboard.

Comment: This works on Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

Since StackExchange can refresh page contents dynamically, the following sequence of events is possible:

1. Page contains some code block(s).
2. Bookmarklet is invoked, adding the button to existing code block(s).
3. Page contents are updated, for example, with a new answer that contains a new code block.
4. Bookmarklet is invoked again, but it refuses add a Select Code button to the new code block.

Therefore, I suggest that the overall structure be changed such that it can be invoked again after a content update.  Here is one approach (assuming that you also take my [previous advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38343/9357) to use `jQuery.before()`):

```
javascript:$("pre.prettyprint").not("button + *").each(function() { 
    …

    var buttonText  = 'Select Code',
        length      = buttonText.length,
        codeBlock   = this,
        $link       = $('<button type="button">' + buttonText + '</button>').click(…);
    $(codeBlock).before( $link );
  });
```

I've changed the selector `$(".prettyprint")` to `$("pre.prettyprint")` because class-only selectors are reputed to be slower.

For the `.not("button + *")` next-sibling filter to work, the button must not be inserted with a `<br>` afterwards.  The `<br>` is unnecessary anyway, since `<pre>` is a block element.